# unable to save JSON through declared mongoosejs schema

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to nodejs and mongoose. Have issue with mongoose schema declaration.

I declared a schema as below:

```
var srouteDetails = new Schema({route_id:String, route_name:String});
var srouteTypes = new Schema({route_type:String, mode_name:String, route:[srouteDetails]});
var smode = new Schema({mode:[srouteTypes]});
```

JSON I am trying to save:

```
{"mode":
        [
          "route_type":"4",
          "mode_name":"Boat",
          "route": [
                    {"route_id":"Boat-F4","route_name":"Charlestown Ferry"},
                    {"route_id":"Boat-F1","route_name":"Hingham Ferry"},
                    {"route_id":"Boat-F3","route_name":"Hull Ferry"}
                   ]
        ]
}
```

Whole program:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var srouteDetails = new Schema({route_id:String, route_name:String});
var srouteTypes = new Schema({route_type:String, mode_name:String, route:[srouteDetails]});
var smode = new Schema({mode:[srouteTypes]});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var routes = mongoose.model('route',smode);

var allroutes = new routes('{"mode": [{"route_type": "4","mode_name": "Boat","route": [{"route_id": "Boat-F4","route_name": "Charlestown Ferry"},{"route_id": "Boat-F1","route_name": "Hingham Ferry"},{"route_id": "Boat-F3","route_name": "Hull Ferry"}]}]}');

allroutes.save(function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Saved");
});
```

ERROR:

```
/Workspace_Js/jsontest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:158
      if (obj && '_id' in obj) continue;
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {"mode": [{"route_type": "4","mode_name": "Boat","route": [{"route_id": "Boat-F4","route_name": "Charlestown Ferry"},{"route_id": "Boat-F1","route_name": "Hingham Ferry"},{"route_id": "Boat-F3","route_name": "Hull Ferry"}]}]}
    at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/Users/Sravan/Workspace_Js/jsontest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:158:27)
    at model.Document (/Users/Sravan/Workspace_Js/jsontest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:57:20)
    at model.Model (/Users/Sravan/Workspace_Js/jsontest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:43:12)
    at new model (/Users/Sravan/Workspace_Js/jsontest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2536:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Sravan/Workspace_Js/jsontest/index.js:12:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.I googled and cant find anything that helped me understand whats wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide the data as a string of JSON to `new routes(...)`, you'll have to first parse it:

```
var allroutes = new routes(JSON.parse('{"mode": []}'));
```

The [`Model` constructor](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model), that `routes()` implements, expects a JavaScript `Object` for its argument rather than a string of JSON.

> **Parameters:**
>
> - `doc` <[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)> values with which to create the document

---

You can also remove the surrounding quotes from the argument to define JavaScript Objects and Arrays with [initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) (from which JSON got some of its syntax):

```
var allroutes = new routes({"mode": []});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this code (a watered-down version of yours) and am able to invoke it with:  node test.js

test.js

```
#!/bin/env node
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var smode = new Schema({ name: String });
var routes = mongoose.model('route', smode);
var allroutes = new routes({ name: 'My first route' });
allroutes.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  routes.findById(allroutes, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(doc);
  })
})
```

You might try trying it one step at a time to build it back to what you had earlier or at least to verify your syntax.  Note that in that line "var allroutes..." the word name is not surrounded by quotes, for example.